# css animation sprite sheet

Tags: css, animation, resize, css-animations

I have a spritesheet with a dice in it; 6 faces.
its face is 70 x 70 pixels
total sprite image is 70 x 420 pixels

now I want to make a CSS animation that goes from 1 to 6 (that's simple)
additionally I want to change the size; at 50% double it size and at 100% back to normal.

```
:local(.mydice)
{
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    background: url('/images/dices.png');   
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    background-size: 100% 600%;
    animation: dicemove1 5s steps(6, end) infinite;
}
```

and then use keyframes to make the alterations:

```
@keyframes dicemove1
{
    0% { background-position: 0px 0px;}
    100% { background-position: 0px -420px; }
}
```

the above CSS snippet works.
but now adding the code to make it grows fails:

```
50% { width: 140px; height: 140px; margin-top: -35px; margin-left: -35px; background-position: 0px ???? }
```

I know background-position must be changed to support the bigger size but problem is I use steps because I don't want to scroll through the image but see it change from face to face (1,2,3,4,5,6)

dividing 100 by 6 doesn't result in a nice round integer which makes the 50% alteration a bit difficult.
Have been looking for keyframes that could handle steps as well but have not found such a thing.
Anyone knows a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

```
transform: scale(2,2);
```

This will grow the dice.
Now I can use 2 animations simultaneously; 1 changing the face other resizing

```
animation: anim1 1s steps(6, end) infinite, anim2 1s steps(36, end) infinite;

@keyframes anim1
{
    0% { background-position: 0px 0px; }
    100% { background-position: 0px -600px; }
}

@keyframes anim2
{
    50% { transform: scale(2,2); }
}
```